# Extremely easy javaScript code did not work

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I used nodeJs to do some simple data processing. `Links` are array with objects with a source and a target.

For example:

```
Links=[{source: 'a', target: 'b'},{source: 'b', target: 'c'}]
```

Now i want to add 4 link to links but it did not work

```
for(var i=0;i<Links.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<2;j++){
      Links.push({
        source: 'yo',
        target: 'yo'
      });
    }
  }
```

The entire program stuck here (goes for infinite loop).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very simply you are adding items to the list you are pushing to so you can never reach the end. The simplest way around would be to save the length of the array to a variable and use that rather than calculating `Links.length` with every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Using the length property of an array will cause an infinite loop if you add items to the array in the loop. You should store the length in a variable instead of using the length in the condition.

Using nested loops in this situation might cause issues if there are more than two elements in the array. At the moment, you add two element for each element already in the array. It means it will add 6 links it there were 3 links in the array at the start of the loop, 8 if there were 4, and so on.

You could do some like this to **strickly** append 4 links to your array no matter how many link there were at the start.

```
startLength = Link.length;

do {
    Link.push({
        source:'yo',
        target:'yo'
    });
} while (Link.length < startLength + 4);
```